# How can I force tortoise-tts to use the same voice throughout a generate speech file?

Tags: nlp, voice, text-to-speech

From time to time, a sentence or a fragment of a sentence somewhere in the text will be read with a different voice.

Example with this [text.txt](https://github.com/neonbjb/tortoise-tts/files/11179986/text.txt):

> What makes jee pee tee-3+ so advanced and powerful? Transformer based Large Language Models like Open AI’s jee pee tee have rapidly advanced in quality and capability. Transformers use an attention weight for each word in the input text, regardless of its position, to better consider long-term dependencies in the text and improve understanding and generation of natural language. They also allow for parallel processing which makes them faster to train and less computationally expensive, enabling the use of larger models with more accurate results. jee pee tee-3 and other similar models have a huge number of parameters (jee pee tee-3 has 175 billion params) giving them significant learning capacity. They are trained on all the text content from the public internet (jee pee tee-3 used 570 gigabytes of compressed text) to predict the probability distribution of the next word given prior words in the text. This simple objective can be performed on raw text without human labeling. When done at scale, it is surprising effective at teaching models to "understand" and generate natural language text.

I used the command:

> /users/franck/workspace/tts//tortoise-tts$ python tortoise/read.py --textfile text.txt --voice freeman,train_empire --preset high_quality --candidates 1 --output_path results/longtexts

The audio file with the  `train_empire` voice was fine ([train_empire.zip](https://github.com/neonbjb/tortoise-tts/files/11179970/train_empire.zip)), but the audio file with the  `freeman` voice had 1 fragment of a sentence with a female voice ("*jee pee tee-3 has 175 billion params) giving them significant learning capacity*"): [selected segment where the voice is messed up.zip](https://github.com/neonbjb/tortoise-tts/files/11179942/selected.segment.where.the.voice.is.messed.up.zip) (for the entire speech: [full speech.zip](https://github.com/neonbjb/tortoise-tts/files/11179943/full.speech.zip)).

How can I force [tortoise-tts](https://github.com/neonbjb/tortoise-tts) to use the same voice throughout a generate speech file?